# Is front shroud more thick than the lower shroud used in impellers ? Thickness of shrouds of shrouded impellers used in turbo pumps of rocket engines

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, turbomachinery

[image: Impeller]

This is an impeller used in turbopumps for increasing the pressure of propellants to drive the rocket engines. I wanted to ask all the engineers currently working in manufacturing of these impellers used in rocket engines, **In general** does the industry use shrouded impellers? And if Yes, Is the **thickness** of *front shroud* (above shroud) greater than *rear shroud* (below shroud)?

Comment: If I had to guess, the default would be that manufacturing considerations drive the choice -> for a cast or additive-manufacture part with subsequent thermal process, this would suggest uniform thickness. Just a guess. In aerospace if shaving off every gram of weight, there might be a justification to thin out one side to a greater degree than the other. Such as if there are substantially different thermal loads or temperatures on the two (axial) ends of the part. NB- I do *not* work in this field